# Mocking a non-virtual function using Google Mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock the function sub so that I can test the function add.I am using non-virtual function,

```
//Non_virtual function
class baseclass {
public:
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + sub(a, b));
    }
    int sub(int c, int d) {
        return (c - d);
    }
};
class mockclass {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(sub, int(int a, int b));

};
TEST(sample_test, testmain) {
    mockclass mo;
    int c = 12;
    int d = 4;
    EXPECT_CALL(mo, sub(c, d))
        .WillOnce(testing::Return(8));
    EXPECT_EQ(mo.add(c, d), 20);
}
```

I don't know how to make the relationship between the add and sub and don't know where I was making mistake.
I can do it with virtual function but I want to do it in non-virtual function.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try the steps suggested in the cookbook? https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock a derived class that calls its base class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750603/how-to-mock-a-derived-class-that-calls-its-base-class-methods)

Comment: virtual method is required for your example, or split and make `baseclass` template.

Comment: I want to do without virtual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible way without virtual:

```
struct MySub
{
    int sub(int c, int d) const { return c - d; }
};

template <typename Sub>
class baseclassT : public Sub
{
public:
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + this->sub(a, b));
    }
};

using baseclass = baseclassT<MySub>; // For prod
```

And then, for test:

```
class MockSub {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(sub, int(int a, int b));
};

TEST(sample_test, testmain)
{
    baseclassT<MockSub> mo;
    int c = 12;
    int d = 4;
    EXPECT_CALL(mo, sub(c, d)).WillOnce(testing::Return(8));
    EXPECT_EQ(mo.add(c, d), 20);
}
```